# Symfony Forms: change an image (or div content) on change

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form in Symfony 3. It has a ChoiceType element.

```
 $builder
        ->add('myChoice', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label'   => 'Choose One',
            'choices' => $this->getMyChoices()
        ]);
```

When a change happens on this choice, how can I change another element of this HTML? Where to start working on it?

I want to do something like this:

Option1: Photo1

Option2: Photo2

If user selects option1, a div element should show Photo1.jpg. If option2, then Photo2.jpg etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the symphony forms can't provide a dynamic update of DOM elements. You need to start working with JavaScript (Ajax) for this.  You need to listen to events, like a change of choice or other related things than build your DOM dynamically with images.